# Java read XML with SAX Parsing

Tags: java, xml, sax

so I started to work with xml and the SAX parser and now I'm trying to figure out how its works, I am familiar with JSON but this doesn't seem to work like JSON. So here is the code I'm work with

```
package com.myalbion.gamedataextractor.handlers;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import com.myalbion.gamedataextractor.Main;
import com.myalbion.gamedataextractor.datatables.Language;
import com.myalbion.gamedataextractor.datatables.Localized;
import com.myalbion.gamedataextractor.datatables.XMLFile;

public class LocalizationXMLFileHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    private String temp;
    Localized localized;
    List<Localized> localizedList;
    Map<Language, String> tempMap;

    /*
     * When the parser encounters plain text (not XML elements),
     * it calls(this method, which accumulates them in a string buffer
     */
    public void characters(char[] buffer, int start, int length) {
           temp = new String(buffer, start, length);
    }


    /*
     * Every time the parser encounters the beginning of a new element,
     * it calls this method, which resets the string buffer
     */ 
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName,
                  String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
           temp = "";
           if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("tu")) {
               localized = new Localized();
               localized.setUniqueName(attributes.getValue("tuid"));

           } else if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("tuv")) {
               tempMap.put(Language.getLanguageFromCode(attributes.getValue("xml:lang")), )
           }
    }

    /*
     * When the parser encounters the end of an element, it calls this method
     */
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
                  throws SAXException {

           if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("tu")) {
                  // add it to the list
                  accList.add(acct);

           } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Name")) {
                  acct.setName(temp);
           } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Id")) {
                  acct.setId(Integer.parseInt(temp));
           } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Amt")) {
                  acct.setAmt(Integer.parseInt(temp));
           }

    } 

}
```

and I am trying to extract the data from this xml File into the tempMap which holds the Language enum and localized Name.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tmx version="1.4">
  <body>
    <tu tuid="@ACCESS_RIGHTS_ACCESS_MODE">
      <tuv xml:lang="EN-US">
        <seg>Access Mode</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="DE-DE">
        <seg>Zugriffsmodus</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="FR-FR">
        <seg>Mode d'accès</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="RU-RU">
        <seg>Доступ</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="PL-PL">
        <seg>Tryb dostępu</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="ES-ES">
        <seg>Modo de acceso</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="PT-BR">
        <seg>Modo de acesso</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="ZH-CN">
        <seg>权限模式</seg>
      </tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="KO-KR">
        <seg>접근 모드</seg>
      </tuv>
    </tu>
  </body>
</tmx>
```

Now at line 49 of the java code I am getting the language code from the tuv attribute but I'm missing the localized Name which is below the tuv called seg of can  receive the parents attribute and get the seg value in the same line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting your text buffer every time you hit a new text node, including a whitespace-only text node like the ones between `</seg>` and `</tuv>`. You need to save the contents of the text buffer when processing the `seg` end tag, and pick it up when processing the `tuv` end tag.

Also you should be aware that the content of a single text node can be supplied in a sequence of calls to text(): the parser can break it up any way it likes (many parsers do this on entity boundaries). You need to accumulate the content by appending to a buffer.

Also note that XML is case-sensitive; you shouldn't really ignore case when testing element names.

And when asking questions on SO, it helps to get the terminology right: referring to elements as attributes is going to confuse people.

Comment: a thanks do you a good tutorial or someone who explains how the SAX parser works, I still don't really understand how it works. coming from JSON it really confuses me.

Comment: You're jumping in at the deep end with SAX: it's a very efficient but very low-level interface for use by experts when performance is really critical. There are much more usable interfaces, e.g. JDOM2 or XOM, or even (if you must) the venerable DOM. But if you really do want to use SAX, read Elliotte Rusty Harold's book on Java and XML first,

Comment: Well I'm am reading xml documents with 6 - 25 MB in size thought SAX is the way tog o since they are big files.

Comment: You'll save a little bit of memory using SAX, but which costs more: 100Mb of memory, or a day of your time?